# Test alignment 'Center' to the highchart legend content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts, text-alignment

I have been working on the highchart for a while, I have the chart like this

[image: Main grap image]

and i have placed the legend at the botton of the page and what i need to do is make the legend text align center like in the following image

[image: legend structure which needed]

I found few question of text alignment in highchart but does not suite my request. So I am unable to move further.

```
Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AbNpB/12/
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Unfortunatley this option is not possible, you can align only legend globally, but not items inside legened

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to align each line using a custom code that will translate each legend item.

It's easier to resize output window in `JSFiddle`: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a02czac2/

```js
$(function() {
  (function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Legend.prototype, 'render', function(proceed) {
      // proceed
      proceed.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));

      // custom
      var legend = this,
        centerRow = function(tab, w, x) {
          var offset = (legend.legendWidth - (x + w)) / 2;
          H.each(tab, function(elem) {
            elem.legendGroup.attr({
              translateX: elem.legendGroup.translateX + offset
            });
          });
        }

      if (legend.options.centerItemLines) {
        var items = legend.allItems || [],
          lastY = items[0] && items[0]._legendItemPos[1],
          rowItems = [],
          pos, prevX, prevW;
        H.each(items, function(item) {
          pos = item._legendItemPos;
          if (pos[1] > lastY) {
            lastY = pos[1];
            centerRow(rowItems, prevW, prevX);
            rowItems = [];
          }
          rowItems.push(item);
          prevX = pos[0];
          prevW = item.legendGroup.getBBox(true).width;
        });
        centerRow(rowItems, prevW, prevX); // last line
      }
    });
  }(Highcharts))

  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container'
    },
    legend: {
      itemStyle: {
        width: 350
      },

      centerItemLines: true

    },
    series: [{
      data: [6, 4, 2],
      name: 'First'
    }, {
      data: [7, 3, 2],
      name: 'Second a longer legend text and longer and longer and longer'
    }, {
      data: [9, 4, 8],
      name: 'Third'
    }, {
      data: [1, 2, 6],
      name: 'Fourth'
    }, {
      data: [4, 6, 4],
      name: 'Fifth'
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this one:

```
   legend: {
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i mean in chart's definition properties set.

Comment: Well, your solution doesnt work, aliging option only center legend position, not items inside.

Comment: yes sebastian is correct, it align the whole legend position only